# How to select whole month with table contain some dates data?

Tags: sql, database, select

How to select whole month with table contain some dates data?

Table:

```
2023-05-01  a
2023-05-03  b
2023-05-15  a
```

how to write a select sql to show

```
2023-05-01  a
2023-05-02  (null)
2023-05-03  b
2023-05-04  (null)
2023-05-05  (null)
2023-05-06  (null)
2023-05-07  (null)
...
```

Comment: You need to build a calendar table and left join it with table containing your sample data. The way you build the calendar table may largely depend on the DBMS you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of integers between 0 and 30. I call it `i` with column `i` .

Then, I select from that table, adding `i` to the date `'2023-05-01'` .

Finally, I left join that table with your in-data.

```
WITH
i(i) AS (
   SELECT tens * 10 + units  AS i
   FROM (
               SELECT 0
     UNION ALL SELECT 1
     UNION ALL SELECT 2
     UNION ALL SELECT 3
     UNION ALL SELECT 4
     UNION ALL SELECT 5
     UNION ALL SELECT 6
     UNION ALL SELECT 7
     UNION ALL SELECT 8
     UNION ALL SELECT 9
   ) units(units)
   CROSS JOIN (
               SELECT 0
     UNION ALL SELECT 1
     UNION ALL SELECT 2
     UNION ALL SELECT 3
   ) tens(tens)
)
,
dt(dt) AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(TIMESTAMPADD('DAY',i,DATE '2023-05-01') AS DATE)
  FROM i
  WHERE i < 31
)
SELECT
  dt.dt
, indata.nm
FROM dt
LEFT JOIN indata USING(dt)
ORDER BY 1;
```

You did not specify the DBMS. In SQL Server, it's `DATEADD()` instead of `TIMESTAMPADD()`.  In Oracle, you have to add `FROM dual` to the end of, for example `SELECT 0`, `UNION ALL SELECT 2` , etc.